# Python getopt recognizing options as arguments

Tags: python, getopt

I'm trying to parse some options when running a Python script.

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"a:p:i:r",["algo=", "population=", "iterations=", "random"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        printUsage()
        sys.exit(1)
    print(args, opts)
    #Afterwards, I parse the options
    #...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

However, when I run this

```
python tsp.py cities.txt -p 4
```

The `print(args, opts)` yields this.

```
(['cities.txt', '-p', '4'], [])
```

Why is it parsing options as arguments?

Comment: You could also use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for more flexible and comfortable argument handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopt` requires that all `-` options come *first*. `-p 4` instead came *after* a non-dash option.

`python tsp.py -p 4 cities.txt` will be parsed correctly.

You may want to switch to using the [`argparse` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead; it is far more flexible and can parse optional command line switches in any location, as it also handles required arguments explicitly.

Comment: Darn it! I had no idea. I was getting dangerously close to not meeting a deadline because of this... Thanks.